# How to store a document inside another document, with Doctrine ODM?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

How to store a document inside another document, with Doctrine ODM?

I don't see an Array or Json type in the documentation.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
class Post {

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $body;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Array
     */
    protected $comments = array();

}
```

I don't want to have a separate collection for comments. I want them saved inside each post.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Comment")
     */
    private $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    private $body;
}
```

But note that comments are not good candidates for embedding — contrary to probably the most popular example of embeds in MongoDB. I started with comments as embeds too, but then run into some problems and decided to store them in a separate collection. I don't remember all the problems, but the main one was the inability to sort comments on the database side. The quick solution was to sort them on the client side, but when it comes to pagination, it just doesn't scale.

Comment: I had tried this before asking, but it said that ArrayCollection() was not valid or something. Lemme check

Comment: Class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection is not a valid document or mapped super class.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? There are some cache problems with MongoDBBundle, so sometimes you need to clear it even when in the dev env.

Comment: Btw, I hope the Comment class is fully qualified in this annotiation `@MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Comment")` in your code. It should be something like `@MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="VendorName\BundleName\Document\Comment")`.

Comment: Yes I noted that I had to use fully qualified class names.

Comment: I'm thinking about moving to propel or mandango. Have you tried them?

Comment: I haven't heard anything about mandango, but personally I don't like Propel because it's still in the ActiveRecord era.

Comment: Yea, I don't like it either, for the same reason. =(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/embedded-mapping.html

Answer (score -2):

In my __construct() I need

```
new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
```

where you just have

```
new ArrayCollection();
```